# Convert NSNumber to hex string with 16 digits

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring

I have to convert an `NSNumber` to a hex string like follows:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llX", self.unsignedLongLongValue];
```

Unfortunately, this will sometimes give me string like `93728A166D1A287` where they should be `093728A166D1A287`, depending on the number.

*Hint: the leading **0**.*

---

I've also tried it with:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%16.llX", self.unsignedLongLongValue];
```

without success.

---

I could do something like this, but that just sucks:

```
- (NSString *)hexValue {
    NSString *hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llX", self.unsignedLongLongValue];
    NSUInteger digitsLeft = 16 - hex.length;

    if (digitsLeft > 0) {
        NSMutableString *zeros = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i < digitsLeft; i++) [zeros appendString:@"0"];
        hex = [zeros stringByAppendingString:hex];
    }

    return hex;
}
```

---

So finally my question, is there a way to enforce the string to be 16 characters?

Comment: `%016llX` (hint: the leading 0)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to zero-pad your hex numbers, use zero in front of the format specifier, like this:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%016llX", self.unsignedLongLongValue];
```

This should take care of formatting your number with 16 digits, regardless of how many "meaningful" digits the number has.

Here is [a demo of this format string](http://ideone.com/AeH72b) in plain C (this part is shared between the two languages).

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that? You were first, so yours will be accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%016llX", self.unsignedLongLongValue];
```

Which sets leading `0` and the length of the output string.